# Conditional formatting with extreme values

Tags: conditional-formatting

I want to apply conditional formatting so that values near 0 (whether positive or negative) are in green and values far from zero (again positive or negative) are in red. I have tried several approaches like writing a formula with absolute values, percentiles and absolute values etc. but no success so far.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have attached the image. Also note that the data may sometimes be asymmetrical  meaning that on occasion the data may only show small negative values (which should be in green) and large positive values which should be in red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

How to create zones with colors based on high and low limits

**How we do this**

Given the data below:

[image]

We select all of the data, on the `Home` tab we click `Conditional Formatting`, then `Manage Rules`. Then click `New Rule..`

From here we click `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`. First we will create a zone for `anything greater than -11 but less than 11` as our first zone:

[image]

Note that in my example I used A4. I did not type $A$4 with dollar signs as I want it to apply to the whole range not just A4. I also made sure that `Applies to` includes my entire range:

[image]

Now all I have to do is add another rule to create the next range so same method as above repeated:

[image]

The last thing to note is that I selected `Stop if True` which basically says that if a line hits one of the rules that is true then it will not look at following rules. With this unchecked it would keep going to check the next rules.